# How long does it take for the ocean conveyor to circulate?

Tags: ocean, thermohaline-circulation, oceanography

What is the period of the thermohaline circulation in the ocean? Obviously, individual particles may take longer or shorter, but what is the average for a small water parcel to do a full loop and end up back in the same place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [NOAA](http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/conveyor.html) It takes almost a 1000 years to complete a cycle. I am not sure how accurate, or where the citation came from their information so take it with a grain of salt. [Lecture notes](http://eesc.columbia.edu/courses/ees/climate/lectures/o_circ.html) from one of Columbia University's 2007 "The Climate System" class suggests this process takes between 100-1000 years. This [paper](http://cdiac.ornl.gov/oceans/glodap/glodap_pdfs/Thermohaline.web.pdf) says Thermohaline Circulation overturns deep water every 600 years or so.

Comment: I've heard 4000 years in a lecture series last week (so I have no quote).

Comment: Yes, the papers cite a time period that I thought quite low. Perhaps I am referencing something different?